# missing frm files for restore

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

We backup a database daily with mysqldump using the following options:

```
--quick --hex-blob --lock-tables --skip-extended-insert  --flush-logs --max_allowed_packet=500M
```

Each database gets its own directory and that directory has a `.sql` file for each table in the database.

I recently tried to do a test restore and I get the following error over and over for each table in the `.sql` file I try to import:

> ERROR 1017 (HY000): Can't find file: './WhateverTableIQuery.frm'
>   (errno: 13)

The `.frm` files are indeed on the source machine but all I'm getting in the backup is tarballs of `.sql` files.

Am I doing the backup wrong or the restore wrong?

Comment: You mentioned that each table has a `.sql` file! Are you doing backup for each table by itself? Normally, each DB would have its own `.sql` file, or all DBs in one file. Verify that please then we go futher

Comment: there is an sql file per table, per database. there are about 70 databases on the server.

Comment: What is the full `mysqldump` command with its options and output redirection?

Comment: Also, make sure please that `WhateverTableIQuery` is an actual table, not a `view` It could be that you're generating a backup of a view.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ perror 13
OS error code  13:  Permission denied
```

Fix the permissions so that "mysql" can read the file.  Keep in mind that the OS 'root' and the mysql 'root' are not the same.